# Can I have my users select a photo from their Instagram account to upload to my website?

Tags: php, api, instagram

I am creating a website that will take in users photos that they select and put it on my site to process.  Can the Instagram API be used like this?  Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: so... you're trying to use instagram to recreate... instagram?

Comment: No, I'm doing a site that will take photos and use them for print projects so I just need to allow the user an easy way to access those photos similar to how I can do it with Facebook, hopefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Check out the: [Instagram Docs](http://instagram.com/developer/)

Essentially, you'll setup OAuth to let users login, and then from there you can allow them to choose pictures and save the image URL so that you can retrieve and use them for whatever you're doing.